# What does "trap" mean in MIPS terminology?

Tags: mips, mips32

What is trap and what does it do? Is it an instruction or part of the processor? Is it a concept related to how the MIPS works?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_%28computing%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Synchronous exceptions, resulting directly from the execution of
>   the program, are called traps.

You can read more about traps [here](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~virgil/cs470/Labs/Lab7.pdf).

Basically, a trap is an exception that occurs at the same place every time a program is executed with the same data and the same memory allocation